# Rails: Toggle a Boolean State with a link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, boolean, toggle

Added an admin view to my rails app (this: http://www.interque.co/). Added a boolean state for approved to each question. I'm trying to toggle that state by clicking a link I've labeled approved.

Here is my controller:

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @questions = Question.all
    unless current_user && current_user.administrator?
        redirect_to root_path
    end
  end
end
```

Here's the admin view I'm working with, which lists all unapproved questions:

```
<% if current_user %>
  <% @questions.each do |question| %>
    <% if question.approved == false %>
    <div>
        Title: <%= question.title %><br>
        Description: <%= question.description %><br>
        <%= link_to "Approve", question_path(question), :method => :put %>
    </div>
    <br>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Can I toggle the state by clicking a link_to? I just need to set question.approved = true.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add remote: true to your link and add a controller action that sets boolean state. You'll probably want to check that link is changed to 'approved' after that (included in the answer). Another good thing will be displaying an error message in case of error and disabling link during request.

config/routes.rb

```
resources :questions do
  member do
    put :approve
  end
end
```

views/admin/index.html.erb

```
<span class="approve-question">
  <%= link_to "Approve", approve_question_path(question), :method => :put, remote: true %>
</span>
```

views/questions/approve.js.erb

```
$('.approve-question').html('Approved');
```

controllers/questions_controller.rb

```
respond_to :js

def approve
  @question = Question.find(params[:id])
  if @question.update(approved: true)
    render
  else
    render @question
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you so much. so helpful. I don't know what drives people to help each other on sites like stack overflow...but it's exactly the type of thing that makes it possible for someone like me to build things. thanks again. --Todd

Comment: For me it's just giving back to community — we all learn from each other theese day, glad that my answer were helpfull